# PHPMailer attachemnt not working

Tags: php, file, email, upload, attachment

i added the upload file function in phpmailer function when i want to send file, it only showing name of file, actual file is missing in attachment.

is there any idea to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Looking for help

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$message=
'Full Name: '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
Subject: '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
Email: '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
Attachment: '.$_POST['attachment'].'<br />
Comments: '.$_POST['comments'].'
';


require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';






$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'lijojohn004@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to




$mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

$mail->addAttachment('attachment');         // Add attachments
$mail->isHTML(true);   
 
 
 

 $mail->addAddress('lijomattathil@gmail.com', 'Website');     // Add a recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!  
 $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
 unset($mail);


}
?>



 
 <html>
<head>
  <title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
     
  <div style="margin: 100px auto 0;width: 300px;">
   <h3>Contact Form</h3>
   <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
     <fieldset>
       <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" />
       <br />
       
       
      <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" >
       <br /> 
       
       <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
       <br />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
     </fieldset>
   </form>
   <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
  </div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to use file upload functionality here, dont need to upload in any directory just get temp path of file and use it as attachment like this $attachment = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; and add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

Comment: see the below answer

Comment: sir  this code am used   mail not going to be send Sending Failed! message will come

Comment: thanks sir  100% working u are very good person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$attachment = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$attachment_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
$message=
'Full Name: '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
Subject: '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
Email: '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
Attachment: '.$attachment.'<br />
Comments: '.$_POST['comments'].'
';


require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';






$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'lijojohn004@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to




$mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

$mail->addAttachment($attachment,$attachment_name);         // Add attachments
$mail->isHTML(true);   
 
 
 

 $mail->addAddress('lijomattathil@gmail.com', 'Website');     // Add a recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!  
 $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
 unset($mail);


}
?>



 
 <html>
<head>
  <title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
     
  <div style="margin: 100px auto 0;width: 300px;">
   <h3>Contact Form</h3>
   <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <fieldset>
       <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" />
       <br />
       
       
      <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" >
       <br /> 
       
       <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
       <br />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
     </fieldset>
   </form>
   <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
  </div>
     
</body>
</html>
```